# Why is different throughput using netperf?

Tags: networking, performance, lan, benchmarking, throughput

I am using netperf on Windows OS, with two computers connected with cross-over cable. First PC is using a Realtek FE network controller, and second PC has a Realtek GBE controller.

With the first PC as a server, and second as a client I get results like this:

```
Recv   Send    Send                          
Socket Socket  Message  Elapsed              
Size   Size    Size     Time     Throughput  
bytes  bytes   bytes    secs.    10^6bits/sec  

  8192  65536  65536    10.00      95.11
```

When I switch things around the second PC is server, and first is client I get results like this:

```
Recv   Send    Send                          
Socket Socket  Message  Elapsed              
Size   Size    Size     Time     Throughput  
bytes  bytes   bytes    secs.    10^6bits/sec  

  65536  8192  8192    10.00      50.11
```

Why is different throughput in this two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because one of the machines is using a poorly tuned TCP window (netperf apparently calls this the Recv Socket Size). During the TCP 3-way handshake that opens a TCP connection, each host communicates what size TCP window it can handle on receive, so the other host knows how much data to put in-flight before waiting for a TCP Ack.

8KiB (8,192 Bytes = 65,536 bits) doesn't allow enough data to be put in-flight given a 100,000,000 bps network and an estimated RTT (Round Trip Time == ping time) of 1ms.

To calculate a proper TCP window to use, you need to calculate your "Bandwidth * Delay Product" (BDP). Ping one machine from the other and note the ping time. On my busy GigE LAN, it's about 1ms right now. I think that's a bit high for GigE, but let's go with it since one end of your link is just 100BASE-TX.

100,000,000 bits per second * 0.001 seconds (1ms) RTT = 100,000 bits

100,000 bits / 8 bits per Byte = 12,500 Bytes

12,500 Bytes / 1024 Bytes per KibiByte = 12.2KiB

So your TCP receive window on the slow machine needs to be at least 50% larger than it is (12.2 instead of 8 KiB).

Then again, if you're using a modern OS like Windows 8.x, this Answer shouldn't apply, because your hosts should have automatic TCP window tuning, so the initially-reported values might not be trustworthy. If you're using an ancient OS like Windows XP, or if automatic TCP window tuning is disabled or not working for some reason, then this applies.